# Why doesn't gcc or build-essential install the latest version of GCC (9 as of today) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: compiling, gcc, lts

What's the reasoning behind it?

Thanks!

Comment: @mikewhatever it kinda answers my question, however I'm still confused as to why gcc specifically is involved in that process too.

Comment: Hm..., gcc is just another package, why shouldn't it get the same treatment? ...not sure why you are confused.

Comment: I think this is not really a duplicate, because the reason `build-essential` doesn't always depend on the latest compilers, and why packages like `gcc` and `g++` don't always provide them, *isn't really* that the latest compilers aren't always officially packaged for Ubuntu (even though it's true that they aren't, and that the reason *for that* is the [StableReleaseUpdates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) policy that is [explained there](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/22949)). Shortly before this was closed, I [posted an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1155338/22949).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On any given Ubuntu release, `build-essential` provides the most commonly needed tools for building packages for that release, by declaring dependencies on various other packages.

Two of the packages `build-essential` always depends on are `gcc` and `g++`. On each release, those packages provide (parts of) the GNU Compiler Collection at the default version for that release, which is the version that is typically used to compile programs for that release. In particular, it is the version that is used to build all the binary packages provided in Ubuntu's official repositories. Another way to say this is that it's *the version that is used to build that release of Ubuntu*.

[Others have pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155286/why-doesnt-gcc-or-build-essential-install-the-latest-version-of-gcc-9-as-of-to#comment1921794_1155286) why Ubuntu releases [deliberately often do not provide the very latest versions of software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software). Although the [StableReleaseUpdates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) policy *does* apply to packages that provide development tools, that nonetheless doesn't really answer why `build-essential` doesn't always depend on the latest tools, because **`build-essential` often doesn't even depend on the latest tools that *are* officially packaged for the release**.

For example, as I write this, the latest stable version of Ubuntu is 19.04. (It's not an LTS release, but it's a stable release.) [The `gcc` and `g++` packages, which `build-essential` depends on, provide GCC 8.3 on Ubuntu 19.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/build-essential). However, GCC 9.1 is packaged in the official repositories for Ubuntu 19.04; it is provided by packages whose names end in `-9`. In particular, for GCC 9.1 instead of GCC 8.3, you would install the [`gcc-9`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/gcc-9) package instead of the [`gcc`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/gcc) package and the [`g++-9`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/g++-9) package instead of the [`g++`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/g++) package. (You don't really have to install one version *instead* of the other; `gcc` and `gcc-9`, as well as `g++` and `g++-9`, can be installed at the same time with no conflicts.)

It's true that the stable release updates policy is the reason Ubuntu 18.04 LTS does not happen to have GCC 9. But that's not the reason the `build-essential`, `gcc`, and `g++` packages give you the older version of GCC--the version that was used to build the binary packages available for the system. (In 18.04 LTS, [that version happens to be GCC 7.2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/build-essential).) **The *point* of `build-essential` is to give you the tools that are recommended, and officially used, for building packages for *your* release**, and the purpose of the `gcc` and `g++` packages is to provide the components of GCC, including the `gcc` and `g++` commands, that are used for that purpose.

So even when an Ubuntu release officially provides later versions of GCC than the version that is used to build the system, *those packages* provide the earlier version.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer I was looking for!